# Process Data after sending response Servlet

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets

I am writing a servlet, where I have to process the user data. But since processing the data takes time, I need to send response that user and data is valid, before I process the data. Is there a way I can first send the response, and then process the data. Something like,

```
response.send();
processData();
```

Thanks

Comment: What if your app blows up after you sent your response and before/during your processing?

Comment: yeah, i have and in my case the processing data is not as important as storing it, which is done earlier. Data is processed just for better user interactivity, which is not a big deal if some data is not processed. Hopefully app will not blow everytime :)                                                                   btw thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the processData in a different thread. ex:

```
if(!processOn){
    processOn = true;
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            processData();
        }
    }.start();
}
response.send();
```

Where proccessOn is a session/static boolean that is used not to relaunch the process twice.

Comment: DON'T spawn threads in `servlets`. It's explicily forbidden by the J2EE standard.

Comment: can you post the link where details have been given,and some solution to the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, however maybe creating a new `Thread` to process the data may help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. You cannot send response and then read the request content. You can however read the request content as a byte array, then send response and then perform application level parsing of the data.